ActiveMQ Artemis: prefer available consumers in MQTT shared subscriptions
I have an ActiveMQ Artemis broker with two MQTT consumers subscribed to topic $share/tasks, with all parts configured to use QoS 2. Messages are distributed among the consumers following the round-robin algorithm, without regards for consumer availability. As such, the following problematic situation can happen:

Broker sends 1 slow task, then 2 quick tasks
Consumer #1 receives and begins the slow task
Consumer #2 receives and completes a quick task
The remaining quick task is assigned to consumer #1, so even though consumer #2 is free, the quick task is blocked

I was hoping manual acknowledgment would be the answer here, only acknowledging the slow task after completion, but messages keep being assigned to consumer #1 even if it has not acknowledged prior ones.

The messages keep being assigned to consumer #1 even if it has not acknowledged prior ones might have the following reasons:

You are using QoS 0 and manual acknowledgment only works with QoS 1 and 2. (based on the https://hivemq.github.io/hivemq-mqtt-client/docs/advanced-usage/ reference you provided)
You have "receiveMaximum" > 1 (receiveMaximum is the maximum number of unacknowledged PUBLISH messages the client can accommodate).

By using QoS 1 or 2 and receiveMaximum=1 you can ensure a consumer does not receive another message until it finishes the current one.

I was already using QoS 2, but did not know about "receiveMaximum", so this was very useful already, thank you. However, it does not seem to make a difference in the observed behavior. My current MQTT connector is configured like this (default configuration, plus your suggested attribute): <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;receiveMaximum=1</acceptor>.

After configuring the "Receive Maximum" from the client (in my case, https://hivemq.github.io/hivemq-mqtt-client/docs/mqtt-operations/connect/#restrictions), everything did work as expected! (To be clear, this setting needed to be combined with manual acknowledgement.)

Configuring receiveMaximum on the acceptor only impacts the broker. In other words, with your configuration the broker is now enforcing MQTT flow control on clients sending messages to it. In your case you need to set this value on the MQTT consumer itself, not on the broker.

@JustinBertram Is it possible to be even more specific, and configure a "Receive Maximum" at the topic level? Parallel to limiting the potentially-slow messages to one at a time, I still want to process other messages arriving through different topics which are trivial to handle.

To be more specific, together with $share/tasks I want to subscribe to task-cancellations (non-shared topic which all consumers should receive). After limiting "receive maximum" to 1, I observe that not all consumers receive the messages in task-cancellations as before, not even after they have completed and acknowledged the task they were performing, if any.

MQTT doesn't specify any way to configure the receive maximum on a per-topic basis. The receive maximum is simply configured on a per-connection basis which means if you need a different receive maximum then you can simply create a different connection.
